# Understanding a certain solution in combinatorics (distinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> What are the number of ways for $42$ students to be in different classes with $6$ teachers, we know that the first two teachers will have 8 students each , $3$ others will have $7$ students and the last one will have $5$ students

---

the solution in the book ${42 \choose 8}  \cdot {34 \choose 8} \cdot {26 \choose 7} \cdot {19 \choose 7} \cdot {12 \choose 7} \cdot {5 \choose 5}= \frac{42!}{8!8!7!7!7!5!}$

what I thought about was
first pick one of the two teachers then the other and so on for each one but why is this wrong?
${2 \choose 1} \cdot {42 \choose 8} \cdot {34 \choose 8} + {3 \choose 1} \cdot {26 \choose 7} \cdot {2 \choose 1} \cdot {19 \choose 7} \cdot {1 \choose 1}\cdot{12 \choose 7}+{1 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 5}$

why is this wrong? don't we have to choose one of the teachers? it says that they are distinguishable

I tried to look at this problem as distributing $42$ distinguishable balls into $6$ different boxes with each having their unique capacity $ 8 = x_1,x_2$ $\space$ $7 = x_3,x_4,x_5$ and $5 = x_6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the solution on your book is right. My though process:

We can just pick one teacher find out how many possibilitys are for him and then move on to the next, as their order doesn't matter
For the first teacher with 8 students there are ${42\choose 8}$ possible ways to give him 8 students.
For the second teacher there are now, when the first one already has 8 students, $42-8 = 34$ possible students left, as he also gets 8 students there are now ${34\choose 8}$ possibilities.
This we repeat and get to all the possibilities by multiplying those for each teacher, similarly as when we multiply the possibilities for a combination lock, and we arrive at $${42\choose 8}{34\choose 8}{26\choose 7}{19\choose 7}{12\choose 7}{5\choose 5} = \frac{42!}{8!8!7!7!7!5!}$$

Comment: thank you , I had a typo 
my question is that wouldn't we need to choose the teacher? like I did ? for example we know that 2 teachers must have 8 students , why don't we choose one of those 2 and multiply? $2 \choose 1$?

Comment: Because the order of the teachers doesn't matter but it matters which teacher they end up with as they are two distinct teachers and not one teacher teaching two classes of 8

Answer (score 2):

First, the solution in book is correct but there's a typo. It should be  ${42 \choose 8}  \cdot {34 \choose 8} \cdot {26 \choose 7} \cdot {19 \choose 7} \cdot {12 \choose 7} \cdot {5 \choose 5}= \frac{42!}{8!8!7!7!7!5!}$ 
The idea is that you can start with any teacher. You will have 42 choose X students for her. Then chose the second teacher, you will have (42 - X) choose Y students and so on. Since each choice impacts the other choice you would need to multiply them.

Comment: thank you but you say start with any teacher , why not multiply by $8 \choose 1$?

Answer (score 2):

You are overcounting. Let's say $X$ and $Y$ are the teachers who will get $8$ students each, and let's say you have students $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1, E_1, F_1, G_1, H_1, A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2, E_2, F_2, G_2, H_2$. For you, the outcomes where:

- First $X$ gets $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1, E_1, F_1, G_1, H_1$ and then $Y$ gets $A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2, E_2, F_2, G_2, H_2$
- First $Y$ gets $A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2, E_2, F_2, G_2, H_2$ and then $X$ gets $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1, E_1, F_1, G_1, H_1$

are counted as *different* outcomes, whereas they are actually *the same*.

Answer (score 2):

It is putting students into **labeled** (by teacher) teams, which is one of the *three common ways* of representing a  **multinomial coefficient**, viz

$$\small{42\choose 8}{34\choose 8}{26\choose 7}{19\choose 7}{12\choose 7}{5\choose 5}$$

$$=\binom{42}{8,8,7,7,7,5}$$

$$= \frac{42!}{8!8!7!7!7!5!}$$

---

### Addressing comment of @adamrk to @linkja answer

The question header should more precisely have been distinguishable objects into **particular** distinguishable boxes (which is what the multinomial coefficient signifies)

If the objects could go to **any** of the boxes, we would have needed to multiply the answer by $\Large\frac{6!}{2!3!1!}$